# Magento2 Getting issue on Reindex SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1070

Tags: magento2, database, reindex, customer-attribute

Getting issue on Reindex, I was about to create a new customer attribute,
How can i fix this, I also need `is_used_in_grid = true`

> Customer Grid indexer process unknown error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1070 Too many key parts specified; max 16
>   parts allowed, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   `customer_grid_flat`

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9609

Comment: I am using 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 hope it should work then